# Heap implementation for numeric types

Tags: c++, error-handling, generics, heap

I am trying to improve the quality of my code as well as trying to study the `Heap` data structure. I have implemented a minHeap (Heap in which minimum value nodes have higher priority). Ref: [link1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-heap/), [link2](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/heap_data_structure.htm), [link3](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/trees/heapspriority-queues/tutorial/). This is the commented code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

// Class for throwing `out of range` exceptions
class OutofRange
{
    std::string error = "The index is out of range.";
public:
    OutofRange()
    {

    }
    std::string what()
    {
        return error;
    }
};

// Class for MinHeap. The `arr` holds the heap elements. The `capacity` indicates total
// allocated space for the heap. The `length` indicates size of the heap.
template<typename T>
class MinHeap
{
    T* arr;
    size_t capacity;
    size_t length;
public:
    MinHeap(size_t);
    T get_min();
    void heapify(int);
    void insert(T);
    T delete_min();
    T delete_by_index(int);
    void print_heap();
};

// Constructor for the heap
template<typename T>
MinHeap<T>::MinHeap(size_t n)
{
    arr = new T[n];
    capacity = n;
    length = 0;
}

// Return the minimum node (root)
template<typename T>
T MinHeap<T>::get_min()
{
    if(length > 0)
    {
        return arr[0];
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Error: Invalid access" << std::endl;
        throw OutofRange{};
    }
}

// Function to put a node at the right position if it has the possibility to move up
// in the heap
template<typename T>
void MinHeap<T>::heapify(int start)
{
    for(int i = start; i > 0; i = (i - 1) / 2)
    {
        if(arr[i] < arr[(i - 1) / 2])
        {
            std::swap(arr[i], arr[(i - 1) / 2]);
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }

}

// Inserts nodes to heap
template<typename T>
void MinHeap<T>::insert(T data)
{
    // Check if capacity is reached
    if(length == capacity)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: Heap capacity reached" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // Insert the node
    arr[length] = data;
    this -> heapify(length);
    length++;
}

// Deletes the minimum value node (root)
template<typename T>
T MinHeap<T>::delete_min()
{
    // Check if heap has any elements/ nodes
    if(length == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: Invalid Access" << std::endl;
        throw OutofRange{};
    }

    // Replace minimum node (root) with the last node
    T del_min = arr[0];
    std::swap(arr[0], arr[length - 1]);
    arr[length - 1] = (T)NULL;
    length--;
    // Bring the new root to correct position based on value
    for(size_t i = 0; i < length - 1 && length > 0;)
    {
        int min_child;
        if(2 * i + 1 > length - 1)
        {
            break;
        }
        if(2 * i + 2 > length - 1)
        {
            min_child = 2 * i + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            min_child = arr[2 * i + 1] <= arr[2 * i + 2] ? 2 * i + 1 : 2 * i + 2;
        }
        if(arr[i] > arr[min_child])
        {
            std::swap(arr[i], arr[min_child]);
        }
        i = min_child;
    }
    return del_min;
}

// Deletes a node by index
template<typename T>
T MinHeap<T>::delete_by_index(int index)
{
    int del_val = arr[index];
    T min_val = std::numeric_limits<T>::min();
    arr[index] = min_val;
    this -> heapify(index);
    this -> delete_min();
    return del_val;
}

// Print the heap
template<typename T>
void MinHeap<T>::print_heap()
{
    std::cout << "The Min Heap: " << std::endl;
    if(length == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Empty" << std::endl;
    }
    for(size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        std::cout << arr[i] << "\t";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        MinHeap<int> h1{10};
        int del_val;
        std::vector<int> input = {35, 33, 42, 10, 14, 19, 27, 44, 26, 31};
        // Insert input values to the heap
        for(size_t i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
        {
            h1.insert(input[i]);
            h1.print_heap();
        }

        // Check if minimum value/ highest priority can be accessed
        std::cout << "Current Root: " << h1.get_min() << std::endl;

        // Delete by index test case
        del_val = h1.delete_by_index(2);
        std::cout << "Delete by index: " << del_val << std::endl;
        h1.print_heap();

        // Delete the minimum value
        for(size_t i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
        {
            del_val = h1.delete_min();
            std::cout << "Deleted value: " << del_val << std::endl;
            h1.print_heap();
        }

        // Uncomment to test exception in deletion if delete_by_index test case is not present.
        //del_val = h1.delete_min();
        //std::cout << "Deleted value: " << del_val << std::endl;

        // Uncomment to test exception in accessing minimum value(root)
        //h1.get_min();
    }
    // Catch the out of range exceptions
    catch(OutofRange& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

1. Are heaps used for data types other than numeric? Even though my implementation uses templates, it does depend on `numeric_limits`. I am assuming that if the data type is not numeric, it can converted to a custom data type like shown below:

   ```
   struct custom_type
   {
       T val;
       int priority;
       custom_type(T v, int p)
       {
           val = v;
           priority = p;
       }
       // Overloads for comparison operators which utilize priority field.
       /*
       -------
       -------
       */
   };
   ```
2. Is there a better way to handle `out of range` errors without using exceptions and not returning a value such as `INT_MAX`, `INT_MIN` or zero?
3. What could be other possible improvements in the code?

Comment: I realize that implementing a heap is a good learning exercise, but if you ever want a better implementation: [`std::make_heap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap) et al. are pretty good.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Memory management

You never `delete[] arr;`, which leaks memory. Not a good thing! There are multiple ways to fix this:

- Adding correct calls to `delete[] arr;` in the right places (remember exceptions, assignments and so on!), which is rather bug-prone.

  Also, `new T[size]` default-constructs `size` objects of type `T` in the contiguous memory. This requires `T` to be default constructible and might be expensive, depending on `T` and `size`.
- Use a `std::unique_ptr<T[]> arr` instead. This will automatically clean up memory, but you still need to keep track of size, capacity etc.

  Still has the default-construction issue from above.
- Use a `std::unique_ptr<std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>[]>`. Similar to above, but without the default-construction issue. Requires placement new, though.
- Use a `std::vector<T>` (or similar container) and let it handle all that memory management stuff. The easiest solution, and hard to screw up. It also makes adding additional features easier, like growing capacity.

I'd suggest using the last option, unless you have some really strong reasons for not using `std::vector`.

## Design

#### Reusing code

At the very lowest level, one could extract the comparison operation and the actual container and write the `heap` logic independently of those. This would allow to reuse the same implementation for many orderings (min-heap, max-heap, ...) and different underlying storage.

#### Member function accessibility

- `heapify` is an internal helper function, and thus shouldn't be accessible to the public.
- `print_heap` might be a handy debugging utility function, but doesn't seem to fit into the finished product.
- How would someone effectively use `delete_by_index`? An outsider doesn't have access to `MinHeap::arr`, so there isn't a good way to determine which indices might contain a value that ought to be removed.

#### Member function names

Most of the remaining `public` facing member functions have names that differ from the usual standard library ones. Examples:

- `get_min` = `top` (or maybe `front`)
- `delete_min` = `pop`
- `insert` = `push` and/or `emplace`

#### Putting it all together

A revised class design could look something like this:

```
template<typename T, typename Container = std::vector<T>, typename Comparer = std::less<typename Container::value_type>>
class heap {
    Container storage{};
    Comparer compare{};

public:
    heap() = default;

    void push(const T& value);
    void push(T&& value);

    template<typename... Args>
    void emplace(Args&&... args);

    void pop();

    const T& top() const; // could return T, but would be expensive for large T

    typename Container::size_type size() const;
    bool empty() const;

private:
    void heapify();
    void bubble_down(typename Container::iterator pos); // could be std::size_t or std::ptrdiff_t instead
};
```

Some of those member functions could be marked `noexcept` (or conditionally `noexcept`), depending on their actual implementation.

## Implementation

- An "out of range" exception is so common that it got included in the `<stdexcept>` standard library header: [`std::out_of_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range). This could be used instead of `OutOfRange`.
- There are lots of random debug messages which get printed to `std::cout`. Either they aren't needed at all, or an exception would convey much better to the caller that something went wrong.

  For example, instead of `std::cout << "Error: Heap capacity reached" << std::endl; return;` (taken from `MinHeap::insert`), throwing an exception like `throw std::out_of_range{ "Max heap capacity reached!" };` would tell the caller that something went wrong.
- `(T)NULL` might not work for non-numeric types `T`. If a default value is wanted, `T{}` could be used instead.
- In many cases there is no need for the costly `heapify` operation. A simpler `bubble_down` operation (like that loop inside `delete_min`) that only checks one branch would often suffice, reducing the complexity of those calls from \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ to \$\mathcal{O}(\log n)\$.
- In `delete_min`, there are two patterns that are repeated quite a lot: `2 * i + 1` and `2 * i + 2`. Would it hurt to give them names, like `left_child` and `right_child`?
- The implementer for type `T` might provide its own free-standing `swap(T&, T&)` function, which usually is better than `std::swap(T&, T&)`. To use that one if it exists, you could add `using std::swap;` at the top of each function where `std::swap` is used, and then replace all calls to `std::swap` with just `swap`. (That way, if a type-specific `swap` function exists, it will be a better match than `std::swap`. `std::swap` will be used as fallback.)
- The bubble-down loop in `delete_min` can exit early if the condition `arr[i] > arr[min_child]` is not true.
- Try to `std::move` values instead of copying them if a strict copy isn't necessary. (Hint: None are in this implementation.) This allows the heap to contain move-only types (like `std::unique_ptr`), which cannot be copied.

## Q & A

1. There are many uses for heaps (or as the standard library calls them: Priority queues), and more often than not they don't operate on pure numbers. Most likely you'll have some objects ordered by a `priority` data member or by some timestamp. Relying on `std::numeric_limits` thus isn't a good idea.

   For deleting a random element, it would be better to swap it with the last element, and then bubble that one up or down as needed.
2. If I understand the question correctly, you seem to want to ask "How can I fail gracefully if I have to return a value?". The simple answer is: You can't. If you need to return a value, that value needs to come from somewhere, and special values like `INT_MIN`, `INT_MAX`, `0`, `-1` or `T{}` just aren't expressive enough since they introduce ambiguities and require special checks by the caller.

   In some cases, if "no result" is an actually expected return value, you can use `std::optional<T>` for that, which makes those checks more explicit.

   In other cases, there is no need for returning a value. For example, `delete_min` doesn't need to return a value (the same value could have been retrieved by calling `get_min` beforehand). If `delete_min`s return type got changed to `void`, it could fail gracefully (not throwing an exception) if the heap were empty.

   > Generally, try to not return values from state modifiers (e.g. insertion or deletion operations), unless those values are an indirect result of those state modifiers themselves (e.g. an iterator pointing to the newly inserted element/to the element after the removed element).
3. See above.

     -

Comment: @skr_robo: I hope I guessed the intent behind the second question correctly. If not, please let me know, so I can better address it.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to write a very detailed answer. I will correct them one by one and post additional questions/ comments if required. Your answer to the second question was spot on. So, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

An addendum to [hoffmale's excellent answer](/a/202102) (read and upvote that one first!):

- Prefer to initialize members, rather than assign them during construction:

  ```
  template<typename T>
  MinHeap<T>::MinHeap(size_t n)
      : arr{new T[n]},
        capacity{n},
        length{0}
  {
  }
  ```

  That's clearer, and allows compiler warnings such as `-Weffc++` let you know if you missed any.
- Consider providing a constructor that accepts a `std::initializer_list`, which can be much more efficient than adding elements one at a time:

  ```
  template<typename T>
  MinHeap<T>::MinHeap(std::initializer_list<T> values)
      : MinHeap(values.size())
  {
      std::copy(values.begin(), values.end(), arr);
      length = values.size();
      heapify(0);
  }
  ```
- `std::size_t` is consistently misspelt.  Either add `using std::size_t;`, or (better, for a header) write it in full, throughout.
- `get_min()` and `print_heap()` shouldn't modify the heap, so declare them `const`.
- No need to explicitly qualify calls to other members using `this->` - that's just unnecessary clutter.
- If you must print error messages, write them to the error stream, rather than mixing them into the output:

  ```
  catch(OutofRange& e)
  {
      std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
  ```
- `delete_by_index` assigns a `T` to `int` in this line:

  ```
  int del_val = arr[index];
  ```

  That looks like it was meant to be

  ```
  const T del_val = arr[index];
  ```

  or perhaps simply

  ```
  const auto del_val = arr[index];
  ```

  Also, this function accepts its index as an `int`, where `std::size_t` is more appropriate - that's also the case for `heapify`.
- Once `delete_by_index()` is fixed to not need `std::numeric_limits`, then `T` is no longer constrained to be an arithmetic type, and we should be able to use any type with a working `<` operator (e.g. `std::string`) as the value type.  In fact, the test program (which doesn't exercise `delete_by_index()`) works with `std::string` once the other minor bugs are fixed.
- In the test program, let's make `input` a `const` value, and use range-based `for` to iterate over it:

  ```
  auto const input = {"35", "33", "42", "10", "14",
                      "19", "27", "44", "26", "31"};


  // Insert input values to the heap
  for (auto const& i: input)
  {
      h1.insert(i);
      h1.print_heap();
  }


  // Delete the minimum value
  for (auto const& i: input)
  {
      del_val = h1.delete_min();
      std::clog << "Deleted value: " << del_val << std::endl;
      h1.print_heap();
  }
  ```
- Finally, consider using a unit-test framework to exercise the code and check that the correct results or exceptions are produced.  Done correctly, that can give a more complete test suite, allowing refactoring to be done with higher confidence against introducing new bugs.  And you don't have to inspect reams of output to be sure that the tests have passed.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out some excellent points. I will take care of them one by one and post additional questions/ comments if required.

Comment: I didn't put too much effort into fixing `delete_by_index` since I cannot see an easy way to get that index in any meaningful manner. However, your suggestions should be nice for a `remove` or `remove_if` like function. // I'm careful with general advice against `this->` inside templates, since it might actually be required in some cases (e.g. refering to a member of a dependent base class). Not the case here, just FYI.

Comment: @hoffmale: Likewise, I only looked at `delete_by_index` when it failed to compile (with `T = std::string`) - I don't see that it has any value to a user.  Thanks for the reminder of where `this->` can be required (I generally lean on the compiler to alert me to those).

Answer (score 6):

```
class OutofRange {
    std::string error = "The index is out of range.";
public:
    OutofRange() {}
```

If no user-declared constructors of any kind are provided for a class type (`struct`, `class`, or `union`), the compiler will always declare a [default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) as an `inline public` member.  If that implicitly-declared default constructor is [odr-used](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use), then the compiler will implicitly provide a definition with the same effect as a user-defined constructor with an empty body and empty initializer list.  That is, if your default constructor does nothing, either `=default` the user-provided explicit declaration or omit the explicit-declaration and let the compiler implicitly generate it.

```
// Implicitly-declared default constructor
class OutofRange {
    std::string error = "The index is out of range.";
public:
    std::string what() { return error; }
}

// Explicitly-declared default constructor that's been =default'd
class OutofRange {
    std::string error = "The index is out of range.";
public:
    OutofRange() = default;
    std::string what() { return error; }
}
```

The standard library provides plenty of exception types ([`<stdexcept>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/stdexcept)) you could be using.

[image: Exception Hierarchy]

If you want to specify your own type, derive from [`std::logic_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/logic_error) or [`std::runtime_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error) or any of their derived types.  For your program, [`std::out_of_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) already exists, so you could use that.  Maybe you want something more specific, like `popped_on_empty`,

```
struct popped_on_empty : public std::out_of_range {
    using std::out_of_range::out_of_range;
};
```

---

```
public:
    void heapify(int);
```

Should this be part of the public api?

---

```
template<typename T>
MinHeap<T>::MinHeap(size_t n)
{
    arr = new T[n];
    capacity = n;
    length = 0;
}
```

Make sure you namespace-qualify names. [`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) is not guaranteed by the standard to exist while [`std::size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) is.

Don't rely on other headers to transitively include files your code is dependent on.  Always include the exact header that you *need*. (`<cstddef>` for `std::size_t`, `<string>` for `std::string`)

Your `minHeap` takes ownership of a dynamic allocation.  You should follow the [rule of five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).  Basically, whenever your class is managing some resource or responsibility, you should consider how the default compiler-generated behavior of the five special member functions operate on that object.  The five special member functions you must consider are the copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, move assignment operator, and destructor.

A better approach is to use a container to manage the memory for you.  If the value semantics of a container behaves correctly with the compiler generated member functions, then you do not have to define them yourself. This is the considered the [rule of zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

When constructing objects, prefer initialization over assignment.  If you have a constant value you are initializing a data member to (like `length` with zero), use the [in-class member initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization).

```
class MinHeap {
    T* arr;
    std::size_t capacity = 0;
    std::size_t length = 0;
```

If you are taking want to initialize a value at construction, use the [constructor member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization).  If a value is initialized at the data member and in the constructor init list, the compiler will initialize the value at the constructor init list.

```
    MinHeap(std::size_t n)
    : arr(new T[n]), capacity(n), length(0) {}

    ~MinHeap() {
        delete[] arr;
    }

    MinHeap(const MinHeap& other);
    MinHeap(MinHeap&& other);
    MinHeap& operator=(const MinHeap& other);
    MinHeap& operator=(MinHeap&& other);
```

Avoid calling `new`/`delete` explicitly.  Use [`std::make_unique<T[]>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) to create a `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` to manage the lifetime of `arr`.  You still need to consider the five special member functions.

---

```
T MinHeap<T>::get_min() {
    if(length > 0) {
        return arr[0];
    } else {
        std::cout << "Error: Invalid access" << std::endl;
        throw OutofRange{};
    }
```

Should `get_min()` return a `const T&`?  Should `get_min()` return the min for a `const MinHeap`? Consider applying [`const`-correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-member-fns) on member functions that only inspect and not mutate.

Do not use `else` after the flow control has been interrupted by a [jump statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements) (`return`, `break`, `continue`, and `goto`).

There is no need to print an error message here. Any information you want to inform the callee should be passed back through the exception.  Let the callee report the error information to the console if they want to.  Use a logging library if you need to track events.

Avoid [`std::endl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl).  Passing the stream manipulator `std::endl` inserts a new line character into the stream and then flushes the stream.  When working with buffered streams, this is often an unexpected side effect.  Just stream the end line character (`'\n'` or `"\n"`).  If you want to flush the stream as well, explicitly state your intent by streaming [`std::flush`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush).

---

```
template<typename T>
void MinHeap<T>::insert(T data) {
    // Check if capacity is reached
    if(length == capacity) {
    /* ... */

    // Insert the node
    arr[length] = data;
    this -> heapify(length);
    length++;
}
```

Don't state in comments what can be clearly stated in code.  Compilers do not read comments.  The added verbosity is not as precise as code and is not updated nearly as often/consistently.  Comments should state what is done, not what is supposed to be done.

```
template<typename T>
void MinHeap<T>::insert(T data) {
    // sort the underlying container using <, percolating the inserted element up the heap
    // until it is inorder with its parent.
```

`length` is an unsigned integral type of at least 32-bits (`std::size_t`). `MinHeap<T>::heapify(int)` is expecting an a signed integral type.  You have a narrowing conversion from `std::size_t` to `int` which could result in a possible loss of data.

---

```
template<typename T> T MinHeap<T>::delete_min() {
    /* ... */
    T del_min = arr[0];
    std::swap(arr[0], arr[length - 1]);
    arr[length - 1] = (T)NULL;
```

You have an accessor (`MinHeap<T>::get_min()`) that returns the minimum in the heap.  Does `MinHeap<T>::delete_min()` also need to provide the minimum?

`NULL` is a macro variable that represents the value 0.  You are doing a C-style cast of 0 to type `T`.  If `T` is a non-integral type, bad things will happen.

If `std::swap` is not specialized for `T`, you'll have a problem.  You can read more about the [std two-step](http://ericniebler.com/2014/10/21/customization-point-design-in-c11-and-beyond/) here.

```
    for(size_t i = 0; i < length - 1 && length > 0;) {
        int min_child;
```

All of your math in this loop has implicit conversions between `std::size_t i` and `int min_child`; from changing signedness to possible precision loss to signed/unsigned comparison.

---

```
template<typename T> void MinHeap<T>::print_heap() { /* ... */ }
```

Should callers have access to the internal heapified array?  I'm not convinced it's necessary.  If you take the adapter approach for your heap class, in which some other container owns the memory, you can make the container a protected member accessible through inheritance.

---

> 1) Are heaps used for data types other than numeric?

Yes.  Anything that can be ordered can be heap sorted.  Uses that immediately spring to mind are:

- Order Statistics (Kth min/max element)
- Heapsort as a fallback for a quadratic converging quicksort
- K-Way merging
- Dijkstra Shortest Path algorithm
- Prim's Minimum Spanning Tree algorithm
- Huffman Encoding
- Process Scheduling

Instead of using an extreme value to represent the priority, consider using a comparator that forces the value to sift up as the minimum (always returns true as being less than its parent).

> 2) Is there a better way to handle out of range errors without using exceptions and not returning a value such as INT_MAX, INT_MIN or zero?

There are many ways to handle the unexpected situation of popping an empty list.  Here are a couple defensive design approaches that checks the preconditions and informs the user of an error:

- Throw an Exception - Control is transferred back to the caller and the caller is forced to either handle the error or let the program crash.
- Return an Optional - The caller receives either the result or nothing in the form of a `nullopt`.  Error information has to be passed through a global error state.  C++17s `std::optional` is designed to work with values, not references.  If you need a specialization that works with references, see [Boost.Optional](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html).  If you need a pre-C++17 drop-in version of [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional), see [absl::optional](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/).
- Return an Either/Variant type - The caller receives the value (or reference/pointer) or an instance of another type, which could be an exception, error code, or error state.  C++17 introduces `std::variant`.  For C++11/14, see [Boost.Variant](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/variant.html) or [absl::variant](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/). For the Either types specialized for error handling, C++20 should introduce Alexandrescu's `std::expected`. Until then, there is [Boost.Outcome](https://github.com/ned14/outcome) (C++14), [Folly::Expected](https://github.com/facebook/folly), and Simon Brand's take on [`expected`](https://github.com/TartanLlama/expected).

The caller is free to ignore the result type unless the [`[[nodiscard]]` attribute](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard) is declared (C++17).

Alternatively, there is the [design-by-contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) approach - There is an assumption that all of the client components that invoke an operation will meet the preconditions specified as required for that operation.  The pop operation requires the container not be empty and calling pop on an empty heap will attempt to pop as if there were an element there.  The expected result is undefined behavior. Formal systems to enforce contracts are coming to C++.  [Boost.Contracts](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/contract/doc/html/index.html) is currently in development.  C++20 will provide [`expects`, `ensures`, and `assert` attributes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/contract).

> 3) What could be other possible improvements in the code?

Besides what is listed, support for move operations. allocator, comparator, projections, [container requirement conformance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container).

Comment: While I like the design-by-contract approach, I don't think it's the correct one to use for public interfaces. Blindly "trusting" user input gets us all kinds of security problems (SQL injections, Heartbleed, ...) or undefined behavior if unchecked. It might be a good choice to use internally, but that requires rigorous discipline to always check pre-conditions at the callsite (if necessary).

Comment: @Snowhawk: Thank you for drawing attention to many details including std::endl, use of libraries for std::string and std::size_t , and the answer for error handling.

Comment: @hoffmale it's the approach used in the standard library. `std::vector::front` on an empty vector is simply UB. The *nice* thing about UB is that you can have different semantics e.g. throwing in a debug build, vs no checking in release

Comment: @Caleth: This approach is used in parts of the standard library, true. However, that's mostly in the name of "zero overhead" performance, and not ease of use. The tradeoff is spending thousands of programmer hours in debugging instead. // Having different semantics between debug and release builds can be a real pain, especially if there is a bug only showing in release mode or if some developer on a project starts relying on debug mode error-checking "features". (Basically, there are two different sets of contracts in debug and release mode.)